# Solving a Bayesian Game

Tags: fixed-point

I am working on voting behavior using game theory. I have a simultaneous move Bayesian game with n-players (voters) who have to vote for one of two candidates or abstain.

Are there softwares or packages for solving such n-player games (finding the Nash equilibria or even approximate Nash-Equilibria) or any other way to do it, as I am unable to do it manually?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with Python? If so there is NashPy; https://github.com/drvinceknight/Nashpy

A demonstration with Prisoner's dilemma at https://towardsdatascience.com/algorithmic-game-theory-with-nashpy-a73caf14296b

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But isn't Nashpy for 2-player case only? I actually need to work with a general n number of voters voting.

Comment: I thought NashPy had n-player support too. Gambit might be useful then. I, for sure, know that it supports at least 4 player games (used it for an assignment long time ago). I dont know how high it can go.